# How to use Tarantool in windows platform

Tags: tarantool

I am new to Tarantool. I would like to connect Tarantool database through ODBC driver in third party applications like Tableau, Power BI.

Please respond for my below queries.

1)  I would like to run Tarantool database server in Windows 10 platform. Is there any possible to install Tarantool in windows platform? If yes, please provide steps and provide link where I can download the Tarantool for windows and how to proceed further to create database.

2) I hope now Tarantool supports SQL standard query.

3) I saw Tarantool Enterprise Architecture in  https://tarantool.io/product/enterprise.  Hence I hope we can connect Tarantool database in third-party applications like Tableau, power BI through ODBC driver.

4) Is there any ODBC driver (for windows 10 platform) available for Tarantool ?

Please correct me If my understanding is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Kavitha M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered on Google Groups by dedok but I thought it would be helpful to duplicate the answer here for future searchers:

1) You can run Tarantool under Windows, but you have to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

2) Tarantool has SQL support, it's in alpha and under active development.

3) You can use Tarantool with Tableau using the WDC connector, ODBC is under development.

4) ODBC and JDBC are under development.

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide

[2] https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool (branch 1.8)

[3] https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors

[4] A later version of JDBC can be found here - https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java